# netsh "Error: 87 The parameter is incorrect" when using hostnameport

Tags: ssl-certificate, netsh

I am using the following netsh command successfully:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=127.0.0.1:9000 appid={7B8DB713-2C51-41B5-AE6F-6DAA07833DBE} certhash=69fed34fdf164e7feac5e17823b94d0f30ab05c5
```

but when I change the "ipport=..." to "hostnameport" it doesn't work:

```
netsh http add sslcert hostnameport=localhost:9000 appid={7B8DB713-2C51-41B5-AE6F-6DAA07833DBE} certhash=69fed34fdf164e7feac5e17823b94d0f30ab05c5
```

I get the following error:
    SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 87
    The parameter is incorrect.

This is the ONLY THING I've changed in the command.  I am still running as administrator, same exact command prompt.  Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is a [bug in the netsh command](https://balofg.wordpress.com/2015/07/09/netsh-add-sslcert-by-hostname/).  When using "hostnameport" you must also add the "certstorename=MY" parameter.  This is the default value for certstorename, and it is explicitly documented as optional.  So my new command is:

```
netsh http add sslcert hostnameport=localhost:9000 appid={7B8DB713-2C51-41B5-AE6F-6DAA07833DBE} certhash=69fed34fdf164e7feac5e17823b94d0f30ab05c5 certstorename=MY
```

Comment: Reading the content of the `?` command, it does state that certstorename is required for hostname configurations. Seems arbitrary, and thanks to your searching I found what I needed. 

The help docs: 
`certstorename - Store name for the certificate. Required for Hostname based configurations. Defaults to MY for IP based configurations. Certificate must be stored in the local machine context.`